# Does a clique always have a Hamiltonian path?

Tags: graph-theory

This isn't homework I'm just preparing for an exam and I came up with this question while I was reviewing the lecture notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivially true: the path $1-2-3-\dots-n$ always exists in the $n$-clique, and is Hamiltonian. You can even complete it in a Hamiltonian cycle.